# Code block in a numbered list messes up numbering python-markdown/mkdocs

Tags: read-the-docs, mkdocs, python-markdown

I am creating a list of instructions for one of my projects in mkdocs, which I believe uses python-markdown as its markdown engine. But when I try to put a fenced code block in between numbers in the list it renders the numbering wrong.

An example of what is failing me (I also tried to put newlines between each backtick fence and the actual words but it still messes up the numbering):

````
1. Click this
```
some code
```
2. Click that
````

which renders something like this:

```
1. Click this

some code

1. Click that
```

Then when I try to indent it it just messes up the rendering:

````
1. Click this
    ```
    some code
    ```
2. Click that
````

To

````
1. Click this ``` some code ```
2. Click that
````

Yes tabbing works, but what if I wanted to do code highlighting with 
```` ```language ````. Is there a way to keep the fenced code blocks, but also maintain the list numbering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pyhton-Markdown's [documentation](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/fenced_code_blocks/#syntax) specifically states (in a red warning box):

> Warning: Fenced Code Blocks are only supported at the document root
>   level. Therefore, they cannot be nested inside lists or blockquotes.

Therefore, you **must** use indented code blocks. Of course, to keep it as a code block, and have it nested, you need to indent it twice:

```
1. Click this

        some code

2. Click that
```

If you want to define a language for your code block, you will need to enable the [CodeHilite](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/code_hilite/) extension using the [markdown_extensions](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#markdown_extensions) config option in your `mkdocs.yml` config file:

```
markdown_extensions:
    codehilite:
        use_pygments: False
```

By setting the `use_pygments` option to `False`, CodeHilite will output the same HTML as fenced code blocks which will then be highlighted by the JS library provided by the MkDocs theme.

Then you need to use [CodeHilite](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/code_hilite/#syntax)'s syntax for defining a language:

```
1. Click this

        :::language    
        some code

2. Click that
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Is there anyway to specify the coding language for highlighting with this method?

Comment: @yo76yo I have updated my answer to include instructions for defining a language.